# Elasticsearch : Index Mapping for integer array

Tags: arrays, indexing, integer, elasticsearch

I have defined the following index mapping for one of the documents:

```
{
   "favorites":{
      "_parent":{
         "type":"activities"
      },
      "properties":{
         "favorite_count":{
            "type":"integer"
         },
         "details":{
            "type":"integer",
            "store":"yes"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

When I try to index the following document :

```
{
      "favorite_count":3,
      "details":[
          1, 25, 4
      ]
}
```

I get the following exception :

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping [details] trying to serialize a value with no field associated with it, current value [1]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeValue(ObjectMapper.java:595)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:467)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeValue(ObjectMapper.java:599)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeArray(ObjectMapper.java:587)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:459)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:507)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:451)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareIndex(InternalIndexShard.java:329)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:521)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

From this link http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/array-type/ , I believe there is no problem with the index mapping. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sort of sounds like you're trying to push values into a field that has a non-compatible mapping - is the mapping you posted above what ES returns, or is it what you want your mapping to be? In either case, make sure that the mapping currently in use in ES matches what you want it to be.  It sounds like you tried to update the mapping after it already had documents.

Comment: The issue is resolved. I was giving the index type name wrong in the rest api url, it should have been 'http://localhost:9200/test-app/favorites/_mapping', I was giving it as http://localhost:9200/test-app/ratings/_mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I was giving the index type name wrong in the rest api url, it should have been 'localhost:9200/test-app/favorites/_mapping';, I was giving it as localhost:9200/test-app/ratings/_mapping.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a parent/child relationship, you need to specify the parent when indexing a child document.  See the Elasticsearch docs here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/  You didn't say how you were indexing these; via curl it should look like this, where `activity-id` is the id of the parent document of this favorite:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/favorites?parent=activity-id -d'
{
      "favorite_count":3,
      "details":[
          1, 25, 4
      ]
}'
```